# How to encode password in cakephp using default security methods?

Tags: security, cakephp, passwords, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp2. I wants to encode my password before it save to the database. These codes are used in my model as,

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {
function registration($name,$uname,$pass){
    $newpass = AuthComponent::password($pass);
    $reg=array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'uname'=>$uname,
            'password'=>$newpass,
            'status'=>'1'
        );
    $this->save($reg);
}
```

}
?>

But while inserting I am getting an error message as,
"Error: Class 'AuthComponent' not found
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\Model\User.php".
How to solve this error ?

Comment: Have you added `Auth` to the `$components` array in your `AppController`?

Comment: also, always call `$this->create()` prior to calling `$this->save()` if you want to insert a new record.

Comment: mark is right, or you can set the `'id' = null`. You should read the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authentication) about Authentication in CakePHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to make sure you have added Auth component, you can do this in appController.php

```
public $components = array(
                 'Auth'
          );
```

Then use your code

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class User extends AppModel {
function registration($name,$uname,$pass){
    $newpass = AuthComponent::password($pass);
    $reg=array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'uname'=>$uname,
            'password'=>$newpass,
            'status'=>'1'
        );
    $this->save($reg);
}
```

i do not think its a good practice to make insertion queries in model. instead a better way is to use the beforesave method in user.php(model) and then make insertion in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a function for encrypting password in your Model file :

```
 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password(
      $this->data['User']['password']
    );
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to save the record in the table in Controller File.Just create a function for encrypting password in your AppController file

```
public function encryptPassword($sPassword = null) {
        return AuthComponent::password($sPassword);
    }
```

Just call the function before saving the Record

```
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = $this -> encryptPassword($this->request->data['User']['password']);
```